# Woocommerce Product Import Automation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I get CSV feeds automatically uploaded into my FTP Server from my suppliers, they're mapped correctly to work with Woocommerce, tested and imported fine but the problem that i face is the suppliers do not have an option to select what product categories i want to include / exclude.

I've purchased a module which will automatically pull the feed from my server and then upload into woocommerce anytime i specify via a cron job, is there a way i can automatically exclude categories from displaying even though they get imported every 4 hours.